# BeautifulSoup Error in Python 3.3

Tags: html, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-3.3

I'm just trying to parse this site and I keep getting errors using BeautifulSoup. Can someone help me and identify the problem?

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import beautifulsoup




html = urllib.request.urlopen('http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Tips:Blue-Eyes_White_Dragon').read()
soup = beautifulsoup.bs4(html)
texts = soup.findAll(text=True)

def visible(element):
    if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', '[document]', 'head', 'title']:
        return False
    elif re.match('<!--.*-->', str(element)):
        return False
    return True

visible_texts = filter(visible, texts)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've mixed up the module and class names. Rather than:

```
import beautifulsoup
```

You need:

```
import bs4
```

And rather than:

```
beautifulsoup.bs4(...)
```

You need:

```
bs4.BeautifulSoup(...)
```

Also, in the newest version of Beautiful Soup, the underscore variants are preferred over the camel-case variants of the names because it fits in better with other Python conventions:

```
soup.find_all(...)
```

Also, depending on what you're doing with `visible_texts`, you may want a `list` rather than a lazy `filter`:

```
visible_texts = list(filter(visible, texts))
```